# Does ios ipv6 rejection issues require apache VPS to be ipv6 with NSURL?

Tags: ios, apache, dns, ipv6

This past week I submitted an update to an IOS app that hasnt been updated
in about 2 yrs.  Apple rejected it based on its failure to access the
network stuff via ipv6.  My NSURL is a hostname (not IP), I shouldnt
need to do anything special since the apple framework will apparently
handle the proper DNS AAAA lookup.

After investigating the issues, I found that I had to do the following:
1. Added a AAAA dns record (at godaddy.com) to my VPS (myhosting.com)
2. Added lines in my CentOS (6.x) httpd.conf (2.4.23) file to:

```
Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Listen [my actual ipv6addr]:443
```

After an apache restart, I type:

```
netstat -tupln | grep 443

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9016/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9458/httpd
```

I dont see my ipv6 apache listener for ipv6, only ipv4's

Is the primary problem here
that CentOS is not setup and/or able to handle ipv6 network connections?

If so, does anyone have a recommendation on a good VPS service thats
low frequency/cheaper for testing that can handle both ipv4 and ipv6?
I currently pay $27 USD/month for this service and I was surprised when
they told me they couldnt handle ipv6.

Thanks

[EDIT]
I failed to mention that I had already set the NAT64/DNS64 network
based on the apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1).
Removed the AAAA DNS record.  Got rid of the apache listen for ipv6.
I have no idea why using NSMutableRequest with a valid hostname is giving me a "request timed out" based on everything Ive read so far.

Comment: Your server doesn't need IPv6, and it shouldn't have a AAAA record unless it does. It's your iOS application that must work on an IPv6-only network.

Comment: When I setup my iMac to create a NAT64 network as apple suggests for testing, my app never hits my apache server (when I watch the logs).  It always says "request timed out".  Apple states that if you use their high level framework (which NSURLRequest is) I should not need to do anything more.  Any idea what else I should look at?  Thanks

Comment: I have successfully used [Linode](https://www.linode.com/pricing) to solve the same problem.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved my problem as well and it was $7/mo cheaper than myhosting.com